# How to search multiple fields using objects.filter

Tags: django

I have the following 3 names in my db

```
cid    name            email
1  |  John Smith   |  jsmith@email.com
1  |  June Bug     |  jbug@email.net
2  |  Rick Ross    |  rross@email.com
```

Is there a way to search 2 parameters as and 'OR' and the last parameter as an 'AND' so the query would be something like this if i pass it like 'm' and for it to search the name or email for the letter 'm', and the also passing it a '1' so that cid=1

So the result would come back as

```
1  |  John Smith   |  jsmith@email.com
1  |  June Bug     |  jbug@email.net
```

And if i did the same search but passing it 'o', it would search the name or email for the letter 'o' and with cid=1 it would give me the following result

```
1  |  John Smith   |  jsmith@email.com
```

Example of objects.filter that i am trying to do

```
Person.objects.filter(name__icontains=name OR email__icontains, id=id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Q` objects. This is the link to its documentation: [complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Your query would be something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

model.objects.filter(Q(name__contains='m') | Q(email__contains='m'), Q(cid=1))
# or
model.objects.filter(Q(name__contains='m') | Q(email__contains='m'), cid=1)
```

Comment: That was perfect, exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much